# Can two ellipsoids meet in a pair of ellipses intersecting in four points?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, geometric-topology, topological-vector-spaces

On the plane two ellipses can intersect in exactly four different points.

In space two ellipsoids can meet in a pair of ellipses intersecting in exactly two different points. For example take $x^{2}+(y/4)^{2}+z^{2}=1$ and $(x/4)^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=1$.

However, it seems impossible for two ellipsoids to intersect in a pair of ellipses intersecting in exactly four different points.

Intuitively it seems this is due to the fact that in such case the ellipses would lie on the same affine plane in space. What is the rigorous way to prove this?

Comment: Did you read the descriptions of these tags at all?  What does this have to do topological vector spaces, geometric topology, linear algebra?

Comment: Why do you say it does not have anything to do with those areas?

Comment: Because it doesn't.  This is just a problem in analytic geometry, so far as I can see.

Comment: Based on what I know about those areas I opine differently.